# Simulation Game - Checking if agent is blocked in

Tags: java, simulation, game-physics

I am trying to program a predator/prey type simulation where these agents of two different types move around in the simulation.Right now I have 8 possible directions of movement (right,forward right,forward etc..) that agents can move in.To make it look more natural I wanted to implement angle based movement like so:

```
xPos+= speed * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
yPos+= speed * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

I have collision detection already implemented in the simulation where agents cannot overlap each other. 
Now the problem I am facing is that how could I check if my agent has been blocked in (boxed in by other agents) and thus not able to move.With previous 8-directional movement what I did is I try to move in one of the eight possible directions and if the agent can't move in that direction (collision or bounds) then remove the direction from possible move directions and try again.Once no movement directions are left then this means the agent has been boxed in.

But how can I check if the agent has been boxed in and if not which angle of movement should it pick next if I was to implement angle based movement(surely checking ever single possible movement angle is very inefficient).Or should I just stick to 8-directional movement?

At the moment the agent moves towards nearest food in view ,otherwise it roams around freely.The agent has no restrictions on how fast it can turn etc (can turn instantly for now).

Comment: First, define the rules of the "agent". For instance, how *should* it move? One very simple method is to just sum up all the "threat" (or "food" or "pheromone") vectors in the immediate area - this is then the vector of travel (or retreat). Of course, that's the "local goal" vector which might have other restrictions on, it: e.g. "can only turn so fast". It becomes a bit more complex for better AI that actually "thinks ahead", but that should be fine for a simple predator/prey game simulation.

Comment: (This same approach can be used to find the "largest opening out", by treating the other N agents as "threats" and trying to avoid them. The vector can also be reduced to a grid cell or discreet movement.)

Comment: Ahh sorry,well the agent really roams around freely with no restrictions on turn speed etc.Before it moves in it's direction it checks whether it is about to collide ( if it was to move in that direction) with any other agents around it (or whether it has reached the bounds of the simulation window).The issue I am having is IF i was to use the angle based movement ( the one that will not collide with anything) how do I pick the next best available movement angle (the one that agent can move in without colliding or reaching bounds) without actually having to check all the 360 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Just check all 4 of the boundaries around your character like you've already been doing, and if they are unavailable, then make the four diagonal movements likewise unavailable.

Comment: Oh sorry miss-worded the question , the real issue I am having that is if the agent is not blocked in how do I pick the next angle to check if the agent can move that way.I mean I could check all the 360 degrees but that would be very costly and not efficient.